# GnuPG for Apple's Leopard 10.5.x

Tags: macos, leopard

I have a Macbook that was given to me by my friend while I save up money for a replacement keyboard on another laptop that run's linux. My question is where can I find a working URL for downloading either the GPG Suite or gpgtools for Apple's Leopard 10.5.8 OS X. The processor is Intel based and if you have another recommendation other than GnuPG projects be my guest, I really just need a PGP compliant program that can encrypt and decrypt files with PKI support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your system is on Leopard rather than Snow Leopard (10.6) will make things a bit trickier. A fair amount of software is only compatible with 10.6 and above.

That said, I'd suggest installing GnuPG using one of the UNIX package managers for Mac OS. I see MacPorts still has a legacy installer for Leopard - see [this link](https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing).

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a binary for 10.5, only 10.6, so you'll need to build it from source, which the MacPorts `port` command will manage for you.

Comment: I already tried installing gnupg through MacPorts way before I tried alternatives but for whatever reason, when the source was compiled, none of the binaries where installed. I'll try again, thank you.

Comment: I already installed GnuPG with MacPorts but apparently the path /opt/local/bin was not automatically added to my path, so I added it and everything from MacPorts now works as intended. Thanks for the effort though.